# Endless loop problem $var gets not set or dont gets updated

Tags: php, variables, while-loop, infinite-loop

I call that script via HTTP, will later done with php-cli. First video encoding i get the correct duration, and right data is entered in the db, but when script gets the second video all works, only the duration is wrong, gets the data from last insert, if i unset the vars i get this error

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: duration
```

and i know this is an endless loop, i have also a sleep command in the script so that the db dont gets called all the time. How i can get it get working that $duration gets the real value. First process its working, second all works besides duration.

Right now im working on windows LAMP, didnt test yet the script on centos

```
while(10) {
        // GET DATA FROM DB

    // CHECK STATUS

    if($check == true) {

    exec("$mencoder $temp_upload_dir$post_filename -o  $temp_upload_dir$r_post_id.mp4 2>&1", $output);

    foreach($output as $error) {
            if(preg_match('/============ Sorry, this file format is not recognized\/supported =============/', $error)) {
                $error1 = "error";
                break;
            }
        }

    if(!isset($error1)) {
    exec("$mp4box $temp_upload_dir$r_post_id.mp4");
    exec($mplayer . " " . $temp_upload_dir . $r_post_id . ".mp4  2>&1", $video);

    foreach($video as $vidlenght) {
        if(preg_match('/ID_LENGTH=/', $vidlenght)) {
            $duration = $vidlenght;
            $duration = explode("=",$duration);
            $duration = $duration['1'];
                break;
        }
    }

    // MOVE FILES

    // UPDATE DB
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, `while(10)` is an infinite loop and as far as I can see the only `break`-statements are within `if`-blocks, that are probably never executed. Sidenote: `($check = true)` --> `=` is the _assignment_, not the compare-operator.

Comment: if is fixed now above was a typo, yeah the loop should run infinitive and should get the latest video to encode, the break are in the foreach loops, if preg_match gets it that it stops the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
while(10)
```

what you are telling the program is

```
while(10==10)
```

While is looking for a boolean value ie (true or false).  Since 10 will equal 10 and always will equal 10, this statement is ALWAYS true.  The only way to exit is to:

```
break;
```

You only have breaks in your foreach loops.  Therefore you have nothing to break out of your while loop.  As for why your variables aren't being set properly, it looks like you are simply breaking out of the foreach loops too soon before they finish looping through the videos.

Comment: What you described is exactly, what the OP _wants_. The problem is, that `break` doesn't work (at least not, like he expects). And by the way `while(10)` is equivalent to `while((boolean) 10)` and not `while(10 == 10)`. Even php doesn't guess operators.

Comment: When I read his comment //Get Data from db I thought he was talking about the while loop getting data out of the db, but now I realize that is actually where his data calls are being made.

Comment: something with the foreach loops dont works after second+ run, the varibles from the foreach are still set from the first run, if i unset them at the end of the script, than i get PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: duration, i will try this today evening on my linux server maybe its only a windows bug

Comment: They are set from the first run only because you are breaking out of the loop.  Therefore they never get set on the second run, because there is no second run.  However when you take out the break they will no longer be set from the first run because you are not throwing them into arrays, they will be set to the last video you find.  Also you are always doing duration['1'], you need to keep a running count and do duration[x].  There is more than one problem here and these may not be all of them.